# Adding new value to key without changing old value in dictionary python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, pycharm

I need to write a code that add information to user's data. What I mean is:

1. Book id: 001, Book Name: Biology, Book Authors: ['Alice', 'Bob'],Available Copies:2
2. Book id: 002, Book Name: Chemistry, Book Authors: ['Alice'], Available Copies: 1

A dictionary includes this information in it. When user want to add this book in his data, I need to add it in his data. And when user want to look at his book which he took. By the way lists that I shown you in examples are also in dictionary. You can understand clearly in this code:

```
list_books = {"001": {"book_name": "Biology", "book_authors": ["Alice", "Bob"], "number_copies": int("2"), "book_id": "001"},
          "002": {"book_name": "Chemistry", "book_authors": ["Alice"], "number_copies": int("1"), "book_id": "002"}}
```

As you see in code, these are information about books. When user wants to take a book, this book should be in his inventory. What I should write for this? I have to use list or dictionary. It is basicly library program.

Comment: It is not clear, what your question is

Comment: Basicly, user wants add a book in his library, in the list_books as you see, for example if his input is "001", this book will be added in his library. But when I want to print what he took from library, what can I do?

Comment: `print(list_books["001"])` should give you the answer

Comment: I dont think you understand me :(

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't very clear but I think this is what you asked.

If you want to add a new book to the list_books dictionary you should use:

```
list_books["003"] = {
    "book_name": "New book", 
    "book_authors": ["Alice", "Bob"], 
    "number_copies": int("69"), 
    "book_id": "003"
}
```

If you want to read the information of a book just use list_books["003"] to get the data.

Comment: I know how I can read information but what I mean is in this file. In 7th page there is a choice 2. Can you look at it?
[link](https://dosya.co/shj2ii348fmy/mp3.pdf.html) _italic_ **bold** `code`